# What is the meaning of option "t" in documentclass beamer?

Tags: beamer, document-classes, latexmk

I couldn't find any reference as to what `t` could imply.
The only thing I could think of, is that it's short for `titlepage`.

`\documentclass[t]{beamer}`

Comment: `beamer` manual, p. 74: Place text of slides at the (vertical) top of the slides.

Comment: @campa ah wow I completely missed that. Thanks, care to answer and I'll accept?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Copy/pasting from the `beamer` manual:

[image]